# RInside cannot find system Renviron with compiled R

Tags: c++, r, rinside

my RInside program `test_rinside` runs well on server with R installed from ubuntu 14.04 sources. After switching to a server with R compiled manually, the RInside program reports fatal error:

```
cannot find system Renviron
Fatal error: unable to open the base package
```

Both two servers prints nothing for environment variable `R_HOME`.
On the compiled R server, the program runs ok if `R_HOME` is manually assigned to `/usr/local/lib64/R`, which is R root on the server.

I'm not familiar with the mechanism of R_HOME. what else can I do to run RInside program `test_rinside` normally without manually specify R_HOME? Thanks!

Comment: A problem of header location? Did you just copy compiled program from one server to another without recompiling?

Comment: yes. the program using RInside header was compiled on server which has r installed from ubuntu repository. I just copy it without recompiling to the second server. you mean `R.h` different location causes error?

Comment: If I am not mistaken the home directory of R is `/usr/lib/R` when installed from repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in your assumptions: you **cannot** copy from one system to another if the *underlying components* have different locations.

Just rebuild on machine two, or just identical layouts (and even in that case I recommend packages -- we do have `r-cran-rinside` as well).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. BTW, I really appreciate your works of Rcpp related packages.

Comment: And a hearty fsck you too to whoever just downvoted this without comment _after it was accepted_ as the answer

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I have no justification to provide.